# multi thread start_new_thread remove items from a global list

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to learn how split a project into several cpus to make it faster, 
this what i want to achieve:

I have a list.
Split that list into smaller chunks.
Each of this chunks is a thread, process etc...
For each item in the chunk remove it from the initial list.
At the end the main list should be empty

Basically split this list into several guys, each guy will remove its items.

I still need to work on the function to split the chunks since it doesn't correctly accommodate the last items of the main list.

This is my first test:

```
from thread import start_new_thread
global lista
lista = range(10, 25)

def print_list(a_list):
    for i in a_list:
        lista.remove(i)
    return

def chunks(lista, num_parts, return_tuples=True):
    """
    split a lista into sections.
    :param lista: list that will be splited
    :param num_parts: amount of sections
    :return: a list of tuples
    """
    n = len(lista)/num_parts
    list_of_tuples = zip(*[iter(lista)]*n)

    if return_tuples is False:
        list_of_list=[]
        for i in list_of_tuples:
            list_of_list.append(list(i))
        return list_of_list
    return list_of_tuples

splited_list = chunks(lista, 4, return_tuples=False)
print splited_list

start_new_thread(print_list, (splited_list[0],))
```

This is what I get:

```
[[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24]]
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

My second test was using threading:

```
from threading import Thread   
global lista
lista = range(10, 25)

def print_list(a_list):
    for index, i in enumerate(a_list):
        lista.remove(i)

def chunks(lista, num_parts, return_tuples=True):
    """
    split a lista into sections.
    :param lista: list that will be splited
    :param num_parts: amount of sections
    :return: a list of tuples
    """
    n = len(lista)/num_parts
    list_of_tuples = zip(*[iter(lista)]*n)

    if return_tuples is False:
        list_of_list=[]
        for i in list_of_tuples:
            list_of_list.append(list(i))
        return list_of_list
    return list_of_tuples

splited_list = chunks(lista, 4, return_tuples=False)
print splited_list

t = Thread(target=print_list, args=(splited_list[0],))
t.start()

# t = Thread(target=print_list,args=(splited_list[1],))
# t.start()

print "\n------"
print lista
print splited_list
```

In this one, doesnt give me any error,  but the list still completes.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not possible to write a multi-threaded program in Python which will use multiple CPU cores at once, due to something called the Global Interpreter Lock.  You'll need to use the `multiprocessing` module to achieve this.

Comment: @sapi: The GIL is an implementation detail of the CPython interpreter. Other Python implementations may or may not have this lock. Jython for instance has not.  The GIL in CPython also just applies to Python bytecode.  Extensions written in C may release the lock and execute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `thread`-module, it's a internal module (and therefore renamed to `_thread` in Python 3). In your first example, the main program terminates before the threads, and some resources are not available any more. Use `threading` all the time.

Comment: `threading` will not enable work to be split over multiple CPUs, due to the GIL.  The OP needs `multiprocessing`

Comment: thanks guys, but i got a little confuse,  is there a module that is old and there should be a new one?    does any one might have a small example on this? just looping and doing something?   thanks again. =)